# What is the 4th array in python cairo for when using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cairo

I recently downloaded cairo for Python and was testing out the functions. It's a lot different from other graphics libraries that I'm used to. I thought the 4th numpy array was for alpha values but all the values in the 4th array are always 255 regardless of color and alpha. Does anyone know what the 4th array does? I understand because numpy.uint8, I would need 4 arrays since the pixel color is stored in 32 bit format but that 4th array never seems to change or get used.

```py
import numpy
import cairo
import math

data = numpy.zeros((200, 200, 4), dtype=numpy.uint8)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(data, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 200, 200)
cr = cairo.Context(surface)

# fill with solid white
cr.set_source_rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
cr.paint()

# draw circle
cr.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, 2*math.pi)
cr.set_line_width(4)
cr.set_source_rgba(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1)
cr.stroke()

# draw line
cr.set_source_rgba(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
cr.set_line_width(1)
cr.move_to(35,40.5)
cr.line_to(51, 40.5)
cr.stroke()

data[0:20, 10:20,0:4] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

# write output
print("B")
print(data[35:51, 35:51, 0])
print("G")
print(data[35:51, 35:51, 1])
print("R")
print(data[35:51, 35:51, 2])
print("?")
print(data[35:51, 35:51, 3])
surface.write_to_png("circle.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

The fourth value is alpha. See https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t

If you want a non-zero value for it, try:

```py
cr.set_source_rgba(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8)
cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
cr.paint()
```

In your code, you first fill everything with opaque white. At this point, all the alpha values become 255 and stay this way through the following drawing code.